# Where can I ask how to use a specific hypothesis test in R?

Tags: discussion, support

I'd like to know where on Stack Exchange I should ask about how to use a specific hypothesis test on R and where to ask if my code tests do what I would like to without theoretical foundation.

Answer (score 8):

There are two components to what you want to know.

1. Which statistical test is appropriate for your specific problem?
2. How to write code to carry out the desired statistical test?

Question (1) is on-topic here, because it is about statistics.

Question (2) is off-topic here, because it is solely about writing code. Depending on the nature of the programming problem you face, there are several sites that could be a good fit. You'll need to read the Help Center for each and make a choice about which site is best.

Comment: I was thinking about put it on stack overflow but I think there aren't many people using statistics there.

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what your specific question is/would be, so I'm not sure of the best place to ask it.

Comment: just look over if my code is doing the test correctly

Comment: Unfortunately, "is my code correct?" questions don't fare well anywhere, even on Stack Overflow. The best kind of question there identifies a specific problem with your code and asks how to fix it. Other way round, there are many, many users of statistics active on Stack Overflow. It's my impression, for example, that it has long since superseded R-help as the best single place to ask questions on R code.  Just now a check on the R tag reports 430,924 questions -- and naturally the number will be higher when anyone reads this.

Comment: @DaviAmérico, I have trouble imagining what such a question would be.  There really isn't much of anything you need to do in R to "do a test correctly".  R does all the work for you, & it's set up that way intentionally, eg, `t.test(x, y)`, will run a t-test correctly w/o you having to worry about how R is calculating the pooled SD. Maybe you could ask, 'how can I check that I got the right answer?' or something like that.